# How to interpret "multiplication" in this representation of $GF(2)$?

Tags: finite-fields, intuition, group-isomorphism

Most students' first encounter with the concept of "isomorphism" -- probably long before they learn the word -- comes from recognizing that the rules for adding odd and even numbers have the same structure as the rules for multiplying positive and negative numbers:  that is, we have

$$\textrm{Even} + \textrm{Even} = \textrm{Even}$$
$$\textrm{Even} + \textrm{Odd} = \textrm{Odd}$$
$$\textrm{Odd} + \textrm{Odd} = \textrm{Even}$$

and also

$$\textrm{Positive} \times \textrm{Positive} = \textrm{Positive}$$
$$\textrm{Positive} \times \textrm{Negative} = \textrm{Negative}$$
$$\textrm{Negative} \times \textrm{Negative} = \textrm{Positive}$$

These two sets of rules are structurally "the same", in the sense that if you replace "Even" with "Positive", "Odd" with "Negative", and "+" with "$\times$", the first set of rules becomes identical with the second set of rules.

More formally, we define this "sameness" as an isomorphism, and we say that the two groups
$$\langle \{\textrm{Even}, \textrm{Odd} \}, + \rangle$$
and
$$\langle \{\textrm{Positive}, \textrm{Negative} \}, \times \rangle$$

are isomorphic — and in fact, both are isomorphic to the group $\mathbb Z/(2)$.  We have the following correspondences:

| Evens and Odds |  | Positives and Negatives |  | $\mathbb Z_2$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Even | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | Positive | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | 0 |
| Odd | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | Negative | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | 1 |
| $+$ | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | $\times$ | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | $+$ (modulo 2) |

But $\mathbb Z/(2)$ is not only a group; it is also a *field*.  That is to say, there is a multiplication operation in $\mathbb Z/(2)$, which corresponds to multiplication in $\{ \textrm{Even}, \textrm{Odd} \}$, and which can be expressed by the following rules:

$$\textrm{Even} \times \textrm{Even} = \textrm{Even}$$
$$\textrm{Even} \times \textrm{Odd} = \textrm{Even}$$
$$\textrm{Odd} \times \textrm{Odd} = \textrm{Odd}$$

My question is:  What, if anything, is the "natural" interpretation of this operation **in the context of positive and negative numbers**?  That is, is there some operation (say $\boxdot$) on integers that obeys the rules

$$\textrm{Positive} \boxdot \textrm{Positive} = \textrm{Positive}$$
$$\textrm{Positive} \boxdot \textrm{Negative} = \textrm{Positive}$$
$$\textrm{Negative} \boxdot \textrm{Negative} = \textrm{Negative}$$

so that we could fill in the middle cell of the bottom row of the following table?

| Evens and Odds |  | Positives and Negatives |  | $\mathbb Z_2$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Even | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | Positive | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | 0 |
| Odd | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | Negative | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | 1 |
| $+$ | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | $\times$ | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | $+$ (modulo 2) |
| $\times$ | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | ???? | $\Longleftrightarrow$ | $\times$ (modulo 2) |

Comment: Your operation looks like projection onto the first element to me

Comment: @MPW From the context it seems as though $\boxdot$ should be commutative, which rules out that solution

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes, I omitted $\textrm{Negative} \boxdot \textrm{Positive} = \textrm{Positive}$ because I thought it was obvious from context that both operations need to be commutative.

Comment: How about "max"? $\max({\rm positive,\ negative})={\rm positive}$, etc?

Comment: Why don't you consider the framework of $\mathbb{Z}/(2) \times \mathbb{Z}/(2) \approx \{+,-\} \times \{even,odd\}$ ?

Comment: Product in $GF(2)$ is the logical `AND`. Here `negative=TRUE` and `positive=FALSE` (leading to Gerry's suggestion). We often use the additive character $\chi: GF(2)\to\{\pm1\}, \chi(x)=(-1)^x$ to give the isomorphism from the additive group of $GF(2)$ to the multiplicative group $\{\pm1\}$. Alas, this won't lead to a natural formula for the "product". Sometimes (the not equally well defined) $x\mapsto 1-2x$ is used, but that doesn't seem to help here either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gerry Myerson has hit the nail on the head. Not only will $\max$ work, but there is a whole field of study which does exactly this - called “max-plus algebra” or “tropical algebra” in honour of its inventor Imre Simon, who lived and worked in Brazil.

The thing is a semiring rather than a ring because “max” has no inverse. It has applications in operational research and when looking at travel across networks. There is a moderately interesting [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_semiring) but a wider search of the Web produces better and more instructive results.

Comment: But OP is asking (and Gerry is suggesting) max as the operation that distributes over multiplication in $\{+,- \}$ not addition so I’m not sure tropical geometry is what’s going on here. Moreover, $\mathbb F_2$ is a bonafide field, not just a semi ring.

Comment: @Ark, OP never mentioned distributivity, and I never gave a thought to it when posting my suggestion.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are right that it was not explicitly mentioned. But if you're looking for an operation $?$ that makes $\{$ positive, negative $\}$ a field with the operations $\times, ?$, then $\times$ and $?$ have to satisfy some distributive property is what I was thinking.

Comment: @Arkady I realize now that max DOES distribute over multiplication, at least when restricted to {+, -}.  max(+, ab) = + =max(+, a)max(+, b), and max(-, ab) = ab = max( -, a)max( -,  b).  So this is exactly what I want!

Comment: @mweiss Gerry's comment to your question already confirms this. You already gave an isomorphism between the two structures and simply wanted an interpretation of the new companion operation to multiplication. So whatever this is would automatically distribute over multiplication.

The point I was making is that the operations in tropical geometry are **addition** and max, not multiplication and max so it's not quite relevant here.